# Oracle Column Based on Another Column

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using an oracle table. Let's pretend I have a simple table that has names and datetimestamps:

```
Name  Time
---   ---
joe   01JAN1970:00:00:01
jane  04MAR2010:20:55:11
julie 22DEC1984:11:11:11
```

I want to add a third column. Let's call it date. I want to truncate off the time.

```
Name  Time               Date
---   ---                ---
joe   01JAN1970:00:00:01 01JAN1970
jane  04MAR2010:20:55:11 04MAR2010
julie 22DEC1984:11:11:11 22DEC1984
```

That could be accomplished easily enough with an update. The trick is, if someone updates julie's Time, I want her Date to automatically update as well:

```
Name   Time               Date
---    ---                ---
joe    01JAN1970:00:00:01 01JAN1970
jane   04MAR2010:20:55:11 04MAR2010
julie  02OCT1999:22:22:22 02OCT1999
```

Is there a simple way to accomplish this with Oracle 11G? Can I set up a trigger to update another column in a row when a certain column changes?

Edit: clarity in example

Comment: I wouldn't store it in the table at all, just add it in your query when you access it or put it in a view.

Comment: Simple answer to your question is "yes".  Lots of information on it if you search "update on trigger".  And I 2nd Jesse's comment - no need for a 2nd column if all it does is repeats the Time column in a different format.

Comment: I actually disagree that there's no reason to have a second column.  I've found many times that it's much harder to query, and much slower to get results, if you are trying to get records from a DATETIME column that are within a certain date range.  So for example, if you want to get all records from Jan 1 1970, if you have the second DATE column, the query is much simpler with no need of a BETWEEN clause, and you can put an index on the DATE column, so it is faster to retrieve the results too.  An index on the DATETIME has little value if almost all record have unique values.

Comment: Thank you all for the great advice! The reason I need it stored in the database (and can't do it dynamically with a query) is to interact with a proprietary 3rd party software that can really only do very basic queries. I like the idea of a virtual column, but if the 3rd party software can't read that easily, I will go with a before update trigger. I am concerned with performance, but I only have about 40K rows in this table, and it only updates once a day, in the middle of the night (usually only about 2000 rows).

Answer (score 0):

I second Jesse's advice to use a view that returns whatever you want.

However, if you really want this to be stored (e.g. in order to create an index on it), you can use a virtual column:

```
create table foo
(
  name varchar(50) not null,
  time timestamp not null,
  plain_date generated always as (to_char(time, 'yyyy-mm-dd'))
);
```

As an alternative you can also use `trunc(time)` but that will still have a time part in it - only set to `00:00:00`. Using `to_char()` ensures you always get the date in the desired format.

Here is a little SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a7f55/2

Comment: trunc(time) might be acceptable, I just want to be able to sort by date and then another column within the third party software.

Answer (score 0):

You should search for documentation on how to create triggers for 'before update'. Be aware though that using triggers is not always the most optimal solution as it can hit performance.

EDIT*: it is not possible to use an 'AFTER UPDATE' trigger to execute an update statement as per oracle doc. ( [Using Triggers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm) ).
However, it would be best to do this in the code, assuming you have an application running on top of this. Again, do you really need to store twice the same information ?

Comment: You could be right, I'd love to see some ref links though. It is possible though to do this through a 'before update' trigger though, without using the 'UPDATE' statement, simply assigning values to :new.variables seems to work. Problem is, this would also need to be implemented in a 'BEFORE INSERT' statement to be consistent. http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/before_update.php